# DeclareVectorInputPort() function runs with error

Tags: drake

together.

i created my own CMake-Project and linked the drake library. However, when I am trying to create my own LeafSystem I receive a segmentation fault from drake when calling DeclareVectorInputPort in the constructor.

`this->DeclareVectorInputPort("test", drake::systems::BasicVector<T>(1));`

Everything else seems to work fine, for example,`this->DeclareVectorOutputPort()`  works fine. Do you know what the problem could be? if need more information, please tell me.

Thanks for your help. Greetings!

Comment: Can you provide some more context -- maybe the block of code that is failing?

Comment: Problem occurred because we were using gcc-8 compiler for our own project while drake is compiled with gcc-7.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. We (probably) solved it by cloning and building drake with gcc-8, too, as we require this for our project. We solved the occuring error of gcc-8 showing undefined reference to std::filesystem by using ghc::filesystem modyifing the following files:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/common/filesystem.h
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/common/filesystem.cc,